# Best way to handle job cancellation on thread

Tags: c++, pthreads, jobs

I wrote a simple job queue that uses a thread to run the jobs in the queue one-by-one. The thread itself is from a pool, so it's lifetime lasts as long as the job queue object is around. The job is popped off the queue, then run() is called on the job, and then it's discarded once finished.

I'm wondering what sorts of paradigms could I use to abort a job in mid-process. The naive approach is to have an abort flag which I check at regular intervals. The problem is that some jobs take a while because of I/O blocking or some other computationally heavy task.

Another option I thought was to kill the thread entirely. This is a potentially dirty and error prone solution.

Are there other ways of doing this?

EDIT: Since I'm in C++ land, is there a way to inject an exception into the other thread? It would immediately break execution and return to the thread main. This would be ideal, I think.

Comment: In case you really do not see any possiblity using the  "*flag"*-àpproach as mentioned, have a look at `pthread_cancel()`.

Comment: Either just go with the flag solution or run a separate process that you can kill. Killing a thread is a bad idea. See http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/interrupt-politely/207100682

Comment: @alk: AFAIK, using `pthread_cancel()` will also cause the thread itself to exit. I'm trying to avoid this. Basically, I'd like a way to cancel the running job so that a clean job queue could be used. One approach would be to recreate the thread.

Comment: Please what is the difference between "*immediately break execution*" (from your edit) and "*cause the thread itself to exit*" (from your comment)?

Comment: @alk: The job queue object should still work like a job queue even after a call to `clean()`, where jobs are aborted and the queue is emptied. Breaking execution would abort the job, but leave the thread running (blocked, and awaiting new jobs). Exiting the thread would be done only when the job queue object is destroyed. I'm open to suggestions on this design as well.

Comment: It's not obvious from your question, that you pre-crreate the threads and seem to be using some thread pool. I had the impression a thread is created to "run" a job, and ends when the job is done or "cancelled", "broken", ...

Comment: @alk: Added better wording.

Comment: So what about making the pooled jop-threads spawn of a worker-thread, which then could be "killed" using `pthread_Cancel()` if needed.

Comment: Also this "*... and return to the thread main.*" is somehow not logical, as threads do not return to some place, they run or end, that's all, at least as long as no thread is waiting to join them.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on implementation of threads you use, there may be different ways to manipulate "abort flag". I would offer to look toward boost.threads & boost.interruption_points. 
UPD: That injects exception in thread, if it's at interruption_point, as you wanted.

But if you have big unsplittable block of heavy calculations, then, I believe, ideologically it have to be finished full. Think, if you see any "moments" where you can stop it, inside this block, then you can split this block on parts, inserting there "abort flag" at those moments.
So, if it is monolith block, there can't be such moments. So you can't interrupt calculations normal way. So you have to wait for their finish.

But you can avoid waiting problems, if you will calculate your heavy block not in separated thread, but in separated process. Then you can kill it without being afraid for dirtying your main process memory, if needs, you can even left it to calculate what it needs for hours, after your main process was closed many minutes ago, and then silently die, if needs. No problems.